# What are forward declarations in C++?

Tags: c++, declaration, forward-declaration

At [this](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/19-header-files/) link, the following was mentioned:

add.cpp:

```
int add(int x, int y)
{
    return x + y;
}
```

main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
 
int add(int x, int y); // forward declaration using function prototype
 
int main()
{
    using namespace std;
    cout << "The sum of 3 and 4 is " << add(3, 4) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

> We used a forward declaration so that the compiler would know what "`add`" was when compiling `main.cpp`. As previously mentioned, writing forward declarations for every function you want to use that lives in another file can get tedious quickly.

Can you explain "**forward declaration**" further? What is the problem if we use it in the `main` function?

Comment: A "forward declaration" really is just a declaration. See (the end of) this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1410563/what-is-the-difference-between-a-definition-and-a-declaration/1410632#1410632

Answer (score 493, accepted):

**Why forward-declare is necessary in C++**

The compiler wants to ensure you haven't made spelling mistakes or passed the wrong number of arguments to the function. So, it insists that it first sees a declaration of 'add' (or any other types, classes, or functions) before it is used.

This really just allows the compiler to do a better job of validating the code and allows it to tidy up loose ends so it can produce a neat-looking object file. If you didn't have to forward declare things, the compiler would produce an object file that would have to contain information about all the possible guesses as to what the function `add` might be. And the linker would have to contain very clever logic to try and work out which `add` you actually intended to call, when the `add` function may live in a different object file the linker is joining with the one that uses add to produce a `dll` or `exe`. It's possible that the linker may get the wrong `add`. Say you wanted to use `int add(int a, float b)`, but accidentally forgot to write it, but the linker found an already existing `int add(int a, int b)` and thought that was the right one and used that instead. Your code would compile, but wouldn't be doing what you expected.

So, just to keep things explicit and avoid guessing, etc, the compiler insists you declare everything before it is used.

**Difference between declaration and definition**

As an aside, it's important to know the difference between a declaration and a definition.  A declaration just gives enough code to show what something looks like, so for a function, this is the return type, calling convention, method name, arguments, and their types. However, the code for the method isn't required. For a definition, you need the declaration and then also the code for the function too.

**How forward-declarations can significantly reduce build times**

You can get the declaration of a function into your current `.cpp` or `.h` file by #includ'ing the header that already contains a declaration of the function. However, this can slow down your compile, especially if you `#include` a header into a `.h` instead of `.cpp` of your program, as everything that #includes the `.h` you're writing would end up #include'ing all the headers you wrote #includes for too. Suddenly, the compiler has #included pages and pages of code that it needs to compile even when you only wanted to use one or two functions. To avoid this, you can use a forward-declaration and just type the declaration of the function yourself at the top of the file. If you're only using a few functions, this can really make your compiles quicker compared to always #including the header. For really large projects, the difference could be an hour or more of compile time bought down to a few minutes.

**Break cyclic references where two definitions both use each other**

Additionally, forward-declarations can help you break cycles. This is where two functions both try to use each other. When this happens (and it is a perfectly valid thing to do), you may `#include` one header file, but that header file tries to `#include` the header file you're currently writing... which then #includes the other header, which #includes the one you're writing. You're stuck in a chicken and egg situation with each header file trying to re #include the other. To solve this, you can forward-declare the parts you need in one of the files and leave the #include out of that file.

Eg:

**File Car.h**

```
#include "Wheel.h"  // Include Wheel's definition so it can be used in Car.
#include <vector>

class Car
{
    std::vector<Wheel> wheels;
};
```

**File Wheel.h**

Hmm... the declaration of `Car` is required here as `Wheel` has a pointer to a `Car`, but `Car.h` can't be included here as it would result in a compiler error. If `Car.h` was included, that would then try to include `Wheel.h` which would include `Car.h` which would include `Wheel.h` and this would go on forever, so instead the compiler raises an error. The solution is to forward declare `Car` instead:

```
class Car;     // forward declaration

class Wheel
{
    Car* car;
};
```

If class `Wheel` had methods which need to call methods of `Car`, those methods could be defined in `Wheel.cpp` and `Wheel.cpp` is now able to include `Car.h` without causing a cycle.

Comment: forward declaration is also necessary when a function is friendly to two or many classes

Comment: Hey Scott, on your point on build times: Would you say it is a common/best practise to always forward declare and include headers as needed in .cpp file? From reading your answer it would appear it should be so, but I'm wondering if there's any caveats?

Comment: @Zepee It's a balance. For quick builds, I would say it is good practise and I  recommend trying it. However, it can take a some effort and extra lines of code that may need to be maintained and updated if type names etc are still being changed (although tools are getting better at renaming stuff automatically). So there is a tradeoff. I've seen code bases where nobody bothers. If you find yourself repeating the same forward defines, you could always put them into a separate header file and include that, something like: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4300696/what-is-the-iosfwd-header

Comment: forward declarations are required when header files refer to each other: ie http://stackoverflow.com/questions/396084/headers-including-each-other-in-c

Comment: I can see this allowing the other devs on my team to be really bad citizens of the codebase. If you don't require a comment with the forward declare, like `// From Car.h` then you can create some hairy situations trying to find a definition down the road, guaranteed.

Comment: "and Wheel.cpp is now able to include Car.h without causing a cycle." erm, even without methods the .cpp could already include Car.h without the cycle. Car.h isn't including the .cpp.

Answer (score 30):

The compiler looks for each symbol being used in the current translation unit is previously declared or not in the current unit. It is just a matter of style providing all method signatures at the beginning of a source file while definitions are provided later. The significant use of it is when you use a pointer to a class as member variable of another class.

```
//foo.h
class bar;    // This is useful
class foo
{
    bar* obj; // Pointer or even a reference.
};

// foo.cpp
#include "bar.h"
#include "foo.h"
```

So, use forward-declarations in classes when ever possible. If your program just has functions( with ho header files), then providing prototypes at the beginning is just a matter of style. This would be anyhow the case had if the header file was present in a normal program with header that has only functions.

Answer (score 15):

Because C++ is parsed from the top down, the compiler needs to know about things before they are used. So, when you reference:

```
int add( int x, int y )
```

in the main function the compiler needs to know it exists. To prove this try moving it to below the main function and you'll get a compiler error.

So a '**Forward Declaration**' is just what it says on the tin. It's declaring something in advance of its use.

Generally you would include forward declarations in a header file and then include that header file in the same way that **iostream** is included.

Answer (score 14):

The term "***forward declaration***" in C++ is mostly only used for *class declarations*. See (the end of) [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1410563/what-is-the-difference-between-a-definition-and-a-declaration/1410632#1410632) for why a "forward declaration" of a class really is just a simple *class declaration* with a fancy name.

In other words, the "forward" just adds ballast to the term, as *any* declaration can be seen as being forward in so far as it declares some identifier *before* it is used.

(As to what is a ***declaration*** as opposed to a ***definition***, again see [What is the difference between a definition and a declaration?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1410563/what-is-the-difference-between-a-definition-and-a-declaration/1410632#1410632))

Answer (score 3):

When the compiler sees `add(3, 4)` it needs to know what that means. With the forward declaration you basically tell the compiler that `add` is a function that takes two ints and returns an int. This is important information for the compiler becaus it needs to put 4 and 5 in the correct representation onto the stack and needs to know what type the thing returned by add is.

At that time, the compiler is not worried about the *actual* implementation of `add`, ie where it is (or if there *is* even one) and if it compiles. That comes into view later, *after* compiling the source files when the linker is invoked.

Answer (score 2):

```
int add(int x, int y); // forward declaration using function prototype
```

> Can you explain "forward declaration"
>   more further? What is the problem if
>   we use it in the main() function?

It's same as `#include"add.h"`. If you know,preprocessor expands the file which you mention in `#include`, in the .cpp file where you write the `#include` directive. That means, if you write `#include"add.h"`, you get the same thing, it is as if you doing "forward declaration".

I'm assuming that `add.h` has this line:

```
int add(int x, int y);
```

Answer (score 2):

one quick addendum regarding: usually you put those forward references into a header file belonging to the .c(pp) file where the function/variable etc. is implemented. in your example it would look like this:
add.h:

```
extern int add(int a, int b);
```

the keyword extern states that the function is actually declared in an external file (could also be a library etc.).
your main.c would look like this:

```
#include 
#include "add.h"

int main()
{
.
.
.
```

Comment: But, don't we only put the declarations in the header file? I think this is why the function is defined in "add.cpp", and thus using forward declarations? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

One problem is, that the compiler does not know, which kind of value is delivered by your function; is assumes, that the function returns an `int` in this case, but this can be as correct as it can be wrong. Another problem is, that the compiler does not know, which kind of arguments your function expects, and cannot warn you, if you are passing values of the wrong kind. There are special "promotion" rules, which apply when passing, say floating point values to an undeclared function (the compiler has to widen them to type double), which is often not, what the function actually expects, leading to hard to find bugs at run-time.